# MVS 2019 - Как исключить из всплывающего списка завершения слов intellisense, зависимости?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Да это замечательная функция, но с некоторыми включенными файлами ( яркий пример "windows.h" ) как сразу её функциональность резко сходит на минималки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Вот как !? Как избавиться от этого мусора в предложениях завершения слов ?*
*Можно ли как то "windows.h" в черный список отправить ?*

**Может кто знаком со способом борьбы с этой напастью ?**

*ps. Не обращайте внимание на using namespace std;*

Comment: Это все корректные предложения. Заголовочные файлы С добавляют все в глобальное пространство имен.

Comment: @user7860670,
Понятное дело что корректное, но 99.9% этого корректного нафиг нужно в любой момент времени.     И вопрос то про это как раз таки, как это можно отрегулировать, чтобы неактуальное не показывало.    Вот я очень хочу чтобы ничего не показывалось из зависимости "windows.h"